# ASP.Net form validation - bypass client side only on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, form-submit, server-side, requiredfieldvalidator

I have a form with a bunch of fields that I am using RequiredFieldValidator, RegularExpressionValidator, and CustomValidator.

I want my form to perform client side checks when tabbing between fields (it currently does this), but I want to force a server side submit when the asp:button is clicked.  Right now, if a form field is determined invalid on the client side, the submit button doesn't do anything.  I want it to submit the page and perform the server side check.

The reason I want this to happen is because I want the page to go back to the top and display all possible issues and make it obvious to the user that there was a problem.  Currently if they didn't see the client side error message, they may just click submit, see nothing happen, and end up confused.

Example field on aspx Page:

```
<asp:TextBox MaxLength="30" ID="LNom" runat="server" /><asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqLNom" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Last Name Required" ControlToValidate="LNom" /><asp:CustomValidator ID="valLNom" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid last name (less than 30 characters in length)." ControlToValidate="LNom" OnServerValidate="ValidationLastName" />
 <asp:Button ID="Submit" Text="Submit" runat="server" onclick="Submit_Click" />
```

Submit button Code Behind:

```
protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.Validate();
    if (Page.IsValid)
    {
      // Do stuff
    }
}
```

Obviously there is a bit more to this, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try asp.net `ValidationSummary`.  See [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.validationsummary(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.validationsummary%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
It does exactly how you want it.  It can be a pop up or inline notification that tells the user what s/he needs to fix.

Answer (score 1):

If you add 'CausesValidation="False"' to your asp:button declaration.  This will cause the postback to happen regardless of the outcome of client side validation

Comment: Thanks I tried this and it worked exactly as I described; however, I decided to use the validation summary.

Comment: The validation summary is propbably the more correct way to get the result you want but it wasn't how you asked the question :)

Comment: Agree, I wasn't thinking about it the right way.  Thanks again for the input.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this client side, no need for a post back. Look into the ValidationSummary control:

http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/control_validationsummary.asp